# Vertical CSS Progress Bar

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I am working on creating a progress meter that comes from the bottom up using only HTML and CSS.  The problem I am facing is that the overlayed image doesn't line up where it belongs.  Could someone please help me out?

**Edit**

Here is the code:

```
<h2>Fall Fest Candy Collection</h2>
<p>The Fall Fest candy collection has begun!  Follow along with the progress bar as we attempt to reach our goal of one million pieces of candy!</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="progress-bar">
<div id="progress-level" style="height: 79%; bottom: 0px; text-align: center;"></div>
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: 15px; text-align: center;">79% collected</p>
<p> </p>
```

Comment: Please post the code here so the question is beneficial after the external page has gone away.

Comment: I just added the code for future use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- On `#progress-bar`, set `position: relative`.
- On `#progress-level`, remove `margin-top: 133px` and add `bottom: 0`. Then, change the `height` to a higher number, say `50%`, so that you can see it working.

[image]

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem using the progress bars from Twitter bootstrap, but when I set the inner item to position:relative, the containing item's border-radius no longer stays in front of the inner item... Any idea why?

Comment: @mikeyUX: Testing with http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#progress the problem happens in Chrome but not Firefox. So, it's probably a WebKit bug.

Comment: @thirtydot:  Thanks - yeah, just looking into this now also... Looks like it's been an issue in all browsers at some point & is an issue with implementation of the css3 spec regarding overflow:hidden + position:relative & border-radius in conjunction -> logged as a bug in chrome http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/s6c8slm5Svo

Answer (score 1):

I fixed with:

```
<div id="progress-level" style="height: 7%; margin-top: 76px; text-align: center;"></div>
```

Changed the top margin to 76px.
That was in Chrome's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using *position:relative* and *bottom* properties to move the #progress-level up, but I can't try it out now, I am on a mobile device ;-) .