# How to vertically align a progress bar in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [progressbar control of twitter-bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#progress).

I want to align it vertically to look like in the following image:

[image: Bootstrap]

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698804/vertical-css-progress-bar), but I'm afraid it does not work now.

So I do this: **http://tinker.io/e69ff/2**

HTML

```
<br>
<div class="progress vertical">
  <div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 70%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-warning" style="width: 20%;"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-danger" style="width: 10%;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.progress.vertical {
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    min-height: 240px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Do you have any tip or advice to get it? If you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: I dont know an exact answer so im simply commenting but logically you would simply get the divs set in height and then use height instead of width in the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Bootstrap 2

Note this is a solution for bootstrap 2:

width 100%, height variable:

```
<br>
<div class="progress vertical">
  <div class="bar bar-success" style="height: 70%;width:100%"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-warning" style="height: 20%;width:100%"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-danger" style="height: 10%;width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

## Bootstrap 3+

I'd like you to refer to the [others comments on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30037399/1275832)

Comment: this solution does not work with twitter-bootstrap 3. There is no class vertical. Also the link in your comment does not work anymore.

Answer (score 20):

Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4 solution.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/elijahmurray/7tgh988z/

[image]

I struggled with finding a good solution to this problem for awhile. Ultimately, I ended up writing my own that is semantically similar to how Bootstrap structures their progress bars.

This solution also doesn't use `transform`, which I found really messed up a lot of things with positioning when using it. Not to mention, it just got confusing with that.

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress progress-bar-vertical">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 60%;">
    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.progress-bar-vertical {
  width: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
  display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
  display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
  align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end; /* Safari 7.0+ */
}

.progress-bar-vertical .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.6s ease;
  transition: height 0.6s ease;
}
```

Vote if this was helpful!

Comment: This answer is good for me. But there still need some tweaks to remove the hardcoded value (such as width: 20px;)

Comment: @Fendy Bootstrap source documentation explicitly defines a height for the  `.progress-bar` class, so defining one for the `.progress-bar-vertical` matches the same syntax. If you are using Less or SASS you can access the same variable that determines the `.progress-bar` height through `@line-height-computed`. Source:  [Bootstrap Source Reference](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/e38f066d8c203c3e032da0ff23cd2d6098ee2dd6/less/progress-bars.less#L28)

Comment: This doesn't work if I have progress bar positioned absolute within another relative positioned element. Setting bottom value to anything removes bar completely: https://jsfiddle.net/7tgh988z/356/

Comment: Regarding my last comment: one should add negative value for this to work

Comment: just curious, what 'things' are you referring to with your comment 'which I found really messed up a lot of things'  and what do you find confusing about rotating an element 90deg

Comment: @mcgraw heights and widths are transposed, and the progress bars weren't as responsive to `col`s and `row`s. General responsiveness degraded as well if I recall.

Comment: @ElijahMurray - heard, but I'll stick with 1 css rule that solved the problem and get back to work :)

Answer (score 7):

this will work:

```
.progress{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

http://codepen.io/mcgraw/pen/eCwvu

Comment: This works great but it's important to also set the transform-origin CSS property as well. If not set it will center align it, which works well in this example but not it you want it left-aligned, starting at the upper left corner. You would need:  `transform-origin: top left;`

Answer (score 2):

Changing the twitter bootstrap progress bar and animation from horizontal position to vertical position

========================================================================

---

---

HTML

---

```
<div class="progress progress-vertical progress-striped active progress-success">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 40px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress progress-vertical progress-striped active progress-danger">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 40px;"></div>
</div>
```

---

CSS

---

```
.progress-vertical {
position: relative;
width: 40px;
min-height: 240px;
float: left;
margin-right: 20px; }
```

---

Modify The Twitter bootstrap.css file as specified below:

```
        @-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
}
@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

---

Change background-repeat to **repeat-y** and the degrees to **0deg**. so, that the animation renders vertically

```
    .progress-danger .bar,
    .progress .bar-danger {
      background-repeat: repeat-y;
      }

.progress-danger.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-danger {
  background-color: #ee5f5b;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

---

Follow the same with the other progress types like success,warning etc and achieve vertical twitter bootstrap progress bars and animations...!

For you have any queries let me know I may help you..!

If any one out there have any optimized solution than this then please let me know..!

Don't forget to support this solution..!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

For the main progress class add the following

```
.progress{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Comment: "If the element is not a flexible item, the flex-direction property has no effect."
Also add `display: flex;` to that it will take effect.

Comment: yes. you are right. edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

**CSS**

```
.progress{
position: absolute;left:50.5%;top:40%;width: 2.5%;height:50%;opacity: 0.8; filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.progress-bar{
  position:absolute;top:20%; width: 100%;height: 80%;
}
```

See complete Code and implementation [here](http://www.technogeekzone.com/2018/09/how-to-create-vertical-progress-bootstrap-4.html)

Comment: Good morning. Your link appears to be broken.