# How to change the twitter bootstrap progressbar from horizontal to vertical

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I want to use twitter bootstrap progressbar in vertical format i.e, +90Degrees.

Comment: did you try anything so far? show us your code

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318375/how-to-align-vertically-a-progress-bar-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Check out the solution by me...!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***And finally i figured it out!***

## **Changing the twitter bootstrap progress bar and animation from horizontal position to vertical position**

---

---

### HTML

```
<div class="progress progress-vertical progress-striped active progress-success">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 40px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress progress-vertical progress-striped active progress-danger">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 40px;"></div>
</div>
```

---

### CSS

```
.progress-vertical {
position: relative;
width: 40px;
min-height: 240px;
float: left;
margin-right: 20px; }
```

---

Modify The Twitter bootstrap.css file as specified below:

```
        @-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
}
@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 40px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

---

Change background-repeat to **repeat-y** and the degrees to **0deg**. so, that the animation renders vertically

```
    .progress-danger .bar,
    .progress .bar-danger {
      background-repeat: repeat-y;
      }

.progress-danger.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-danger {
  background-color: #ee5f5b;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

---

Follow the same with the other progress types like success,warning etc and achieve vertical twitter bootstrap progress bars and animations...!

For you have any queries let me know I may help you..!

If any one out there have any optimized solution than this then please let me know..!

Don't forget to support this solution..!

Enjoy!

Comment: please can you provide a full working example on jsfiddle or jsbin because I did everything step by step and it didn't work. The bar was flipped vertically but the progress of the bar took up the whole height.

Answer (score 6):

you can use transform: rotate(-90deg) on the .progress element - worked for me. http://codepen.io/mcg73/pen/eCwvu/

the markup:

```
<div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="90"></div>
</div>
```

the css that rotates the element:

```
.progress{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.progress.vertical {
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    min-height: 240px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress vertical">
  <div class="bar bar-success" style="height: 70%;width:100%"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-warning" style="height: 20%;width:100%"></div>
  <div class="bar bar-danger" style="height: 10%;width:100%"></div>
</div>
```