# Bootstrap Css - vertically aligned progress bar with label

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, rotation

I have been given a screen design for a website with a vertically rotated component that I am trying to write the css and html for.  The design is as follows:

[image]

As I am using bootstrap, I decided to customise the existing `.progressbar` by rotating it by 90 degrees in order to fit the design.

My html is as follows:

```
<div class="progress verticalrotate">
   <div class="progress-bar green" role="progressbar" style="width:40%"></div>
   <div class="progress-bar amber" role="progressbar" style="width:10%"></div>
   <div class="progress-bar red" role="progressbar" style="width:20%"></div>
</div>
```

I created the following css:

```
.verticalrotate{transform: rotate(-90deg);transform-origin: right, top;-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);-ms-transform-origin:right, top;-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);-webkit-transform-origin:right, top}
.amber{background-color:#ffb800}
.green{background-color:#00ae3f}
.red{background-color:#ff2635}
```

I see the screen as potentially laid out in the following way:

[image]

I can't seem to get the progress bar full height (tried hard coding width to `500px` but doesn't work) and aligned in the grid correctly (or responsively changing size with the window size changing).  Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong? :(  Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to rotate that element? It's not really necessary to achieve what you want, I reckon...

Comment: Nope - not really!! :-)  I'd prefer a non-rotated solution if you happen to know any!

Comment: See another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318375/how-to-align-vertically-a-progress-bar-in-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the trick is to use `width: 100vh;` for `.progress`. In this way, the width of `.progress` will be the window's height so when you rotate it, it will take the full height.

**Demo**

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

.verticalrotate {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform-origin:right top;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin:right top
}

.progress {
  width: 100vh;  
}

.amber {
  background-color:#ffb800 !important;
}

.green {
  background-color:#00ae3f !important;
}

.red {
  background-color:#ff2635 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="progress verticalrotate">
   <div class="progress-bar green" role="progressbar" style="width:40%"></div>
   <div class="progress-bar amber" role="progressbar" style="width:10%"></div>
   <div class="progress-bar red" role="progressbar" style="width:20%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: WORKS BRILLIANTLY! Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck.