# Vertical Multiple Bootstrap Progress Bars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, progress-bar

My code is based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34803778/6580518) here in Stack, and what I want to do is a multiple progress-bar, but instead of stacking the progress bars up, it is vertically aligning them.

**[FIDDLE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZQyOy)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress progress-bar-vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 10%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 10%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
.progress-bar-vertical
    width: 35px
    min-height: 186px
    margin-right: 20px
    float: left
    border-radius: 10px !important
    display: -webkit-box
    display: -ms-flexbox
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: flex
    align-items: flex-end
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end

.progress-bar-vertical .progress-bar
    width: 100%
    height: 0
    -webkit-transition: height 0.6s ease
    -o-transition: height 0.6s ease
    transition: height 0.6s ease
```

**RESULT**

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the flex direction and setting it to 'column-reverse' is likely what you were looking for

```
.progress-bar-vertical{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
 }
```

Here is the full resource for [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
and here is a great ['cheatsheet'](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body{
    padding: 45px;
}
  
.progress-bar-vertical{
    width: 35px;
    min-height: 286px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
 }   


.progress-bar-vertical .progress-bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.6s ease;
    transition: height 0.6s ease;
    display:block;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress progress-bar-vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 10%;">
        <span class="sr-only">10% Complete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 20%;">
        <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/happymacarts/pen/OjQEaJ

**an alternate option is here that does not use `flex`**

**Notice also that I added a `transform:rotate(180deg);` to make it stack from the bottom up (Kinda hacky, but it worked)**

```css
body{
    padding: 45px;
}
  
.progress-bar-vertical{
    width: 35px;
    min-height: 286px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
 }   


.progress-bar-vertical .progress-bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.6s ease;
    transition: height 0.6s ease;
    display:block;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress progress-bar-vertical" style="    transform:rotate(180deg)">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 60%;">
        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 10%;">
        <span class="sr-only">10% Complete</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: 20%;">
        <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @happymacarts, thats exactly what I needed! The flex method is the best option for me!